# Can not switch Google Sheets sidebar to fullscreen

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, sandbox, sidebar

We have a Google Sheets Add-On that opens creates a 3D view (via BabylonJS) in the sidebar (to display its results).

The 3D view in the sidebar can be displayed fullscreen (by clicking on it).

This works in Google Chrome but not in Firefox.

So I looked in the HTML source of the sidebar and found that the sidebar itself is an IFRAME (id=userHtmlFrame) which contains allow="fullscreen *;" in Chrome but not in Firefox.

[image: Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

I opened an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160428453

Comment: *allow="fullscreen *;" in Chrome but not in FIrefox.* Screenshots please.  If that's the case, you should create a issue in issuetracker and link it here for wider support. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: I have created an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/160428453

Comment: [Edit] it into your question or add it as a answer.

Comment: It seems your issue is declined  because you asked as a question( basically copy pasted this question). Consider rewriting it to their issue tracker template (See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)), if you can't convince  the maintaner that the issue is that google controlled iframe is not providing fullscreen sandbox attributes to Firefox (`fullscreen*`) and that this is controlled by Google exclusively. Consider linking this stackoverflow question there too.

Comment: There was no question in the issue. I included a reference to the stackoverflow question now.

Comment: Issue Reopened. Kindly include the screenshots here as well. Add the tracker link as edit to your question or add it as a answer.